# SWIG general questions

Tags: python, c++, namespaces, inline, swig

I'm learning SWIG and I'm trying to understand some c++ possible situations which i haven't been able to figure out after looking the docs&examples, here's my content:

usecase1.h

```
#ifndef __USECASE1_H__
#define __USECASE1_H__

namespace foo_namespace {
    int usecase1_f1( float b, float c, float *res );
}

#endif
```

usecase1.cpp

```
int usecase1_f1( float b, float c, float *res )
{
    return 1;
}
```

usecase2.h

```
#ifndef __USECASE2_H__
#define __USECASE2_H__

extern double usecase2_v1;

int usecase2_f1(int n);
char *usecase2_f2();

#endif
```

usecase2.cpp

```
#include <time.h>

double usecase2_v1 = 3.0;

int usecase2_f1(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    else return n * usecase2_f1(n - 1);
}

char *usecase2_f2()
{
    time_t ltime;
    time(&ltime);
    return ctime(&ltime);
}
```

usecase3.h

```
#ifndef __USECASE3_h__
#define __USECASE3_h__

#include <math.h>

namespace foo_namespace {
    static inline float usecase3_f1( float x )
    {
        return 31.0f;
    }
}

#endif
```

example1_working.i

```
%module example

%{
    int usecase1_f1( float b, float c, float *res );
    #include "usecase2.h"
%}

int usecase1_f1( float b, float c, float *res );

%include "usecase2.h"
```

example2_not_working.i

```
%module example

%{
    #include "usecase1.h"
    #include "usecase2.h"
%}

%include "usecase1.h"
%include "usecase2.h"
```

QUESTIONS

- Declaring explicitely namespaced functions like in `example1_working.i` will work but I'd like to use the headers instead, it seems swig messes up with namespaces, is there any workaround?
- How can i wrap namespaced functions declared as static inline in the swig file (usecase3.h)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're passing -c++ to swig when you run it, C++ support isn't enabled by default.
See here for more details on wrapping C++ - http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html